# SQLite database error: No such table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have used the `DataBaseHelper` class to copy a `SQLite` database file from the `assets` folder, but when I run this code :

```
DataBaseHelper dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data", null);
```

I get this error :   `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: data`
But I am sure that that table exists...

class code :

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.amin.rendertest/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "db.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

    }

    public void crateDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean vtVarMi = isDatabaseExist();

        if (!vtVarMi) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    private boolean isDatabaseExist() {
        SQLiteDatabase kontrol = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            kontrol = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            kontrol = null;
        }

        if (kontrol != null) {
            kontrol.close();
        }
        return kontrol != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    public Cursor Sample_use_of_helper() {

        return myDataBase.query("TABLE_NAME", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)  {
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there's no table named `data` in yout db. By the way, I'd use better names other than "data" and "db.db"

Comment: Frank, the table exists, but i tried it with other table name and other databases but i go the error anyway

Comment: Check if the db is copied correctly. I.e.: copy it on the PC and try to inspect it.

Comment: thats it ,its not coppied correctly! my database size is 6mb but coppied database size is 12kb , i try with other databases , all coppied databases is the same ,12kb !

Comment: This means that there's some issue in the way you are copying the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem Solved

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

its work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this class .

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
     private static String DB_NAME = "database_db.sqlite";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";



    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        Log.d("path", DB_PATH);
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase(DB_NAME,DB_NAME);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase(String assest , String db) throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(assest); 
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + db;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)    {

    }
```

Happy coding..

Comment: tanQ , i check the file size of databases copied into data/data/PACKAGE/databases , all the databases size was 12kb ! ! (also with your class code)  (sry for my bad eng)